# How to match the start of a line using a Visual Studio Code regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to perform a simple operation: take a file and put "> " at the front of every line. However, when I try to use Visual Studio Code to do it, the regular expression "^" doesn't match all the lines. In particular, it matches:

- blank lines
- lines starting with "-", "{" or " "
  but not
- lines starting with a letter

This makes no sense to me, I'm told it uses Rust's regular expression engine but I can't see anything in the documentation that would suggest this would happen.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

[image: well this isn't ideal]

This is what happens if I try "^.".

[image: ^.]

Comment: What's your version of VSC? It would be nice if we had a chance to see a screen shot of highlighted matches.

Comment: Sorry to ask about something that's probably obvious, but are you sure they're actually separate lines (not line wrapping)?

Comment: It worked for me (VSCode 1.21), as @CAustin mentioned it doesn't match line wrapping

Comment: "^" works for me too - matches all lines.

Comment: I'm on 1.15.1. Screenshot added.

Comment: It almost looks as if there is a space after the ^ in the find dialog like "^ " - except for that one } on line 30 that is properly selected.?  Does ^.{0} work better for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the correct answer is: because match whole word is switched on. This is visible in the screenshot above, but not very obvious.

Answer (score 8):

The Visual Studio text editor has a Regex implementation.  You could populate this with some of your data and develop your Regex expression manually before you code it.  I'm looking at Visual Studio Code (an MS product) on Linux and using the equivalent of

Search   ^(.*)$
Replace  >$1

in the editor I may have solved your problem.

```
-999 
{42

 uuu
AAA
```

becomes

```
>-999
>{42
>
> uuu
>AAA
```

This Regex technique is called group capturing.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer since it does actually work, but I'm none the wiser as to why the obvious thing doesn't work. Nor do I understand why it seems to work for so may other people.

Answer (score 0):

just add an anchor `^`

```
^my_pattern
```

That is if you are just trying to match to the start of the line (like the question asks):